# How to check with rspec if a method(e.g. #each) returns an Enumerator when no block is given?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I defined `my_each` method in the `enumerable_methods.rb`. It works the same as `#each`: when no block is given it returns an Enumerator. In my `enumerable_methods_spec.rb`:

```
describe Enumerable do
  let(:array) {[1,2,3,4]}
  let(:answer) {[]}

  describe "#my_each" do
    ...

    context "when no block is given" do
      it "returns an Enumerator" do
        expect(array.my_each).to eql(array.to_enum(:my_each))
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I got this error in terminal:

```
Failures:

  1) Enumerable#my_each when no block is given returns an Enumerator
     Failure/Error: expect(array.my_each).to eql(array.to_enum(:my_each))

       expected: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:my_each>
            got: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:my_each>

       (compared using eql?)

       Diff:

     # ./enumerable_methods_spec.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02475 seconds (files took 0.12087 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure
```

I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the test into two:

```
expect(array.my_each).to be_a(Enumerator)
expect(array.my_each.to_a).to eq(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this?

```
expect(array.my_each).to be_an Enumerator
```

An actual content check would also be useful, as shown in @mudasobwa's answer.

Comment: False positives if `my_each` returns, say, a reversed enumerator?

Comment: @mudasobwa Well, the question was "how do I check it returns me an enumerator" :) So I answered that. But yes, a second part of your answer will also be useful in a real test.

Answer (score 0):

`expect(array.my_each.inspect).to eql(array.to_enum(:my_each).inspect)`